# PHP redirect - break out of iframe

Tags: php, symfony

I know this is very basic and I've never had the need before, but I want a PHP redirect to break out of any iframe (if applicable).

Is this possible?

I know that PHP sends a header to the browser, so it should be, but I can't see this anywhere.

So if I use this code then it always changes the parent and not just any iframe window:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://domain.com/');
?>
```

Of course this works, but I need it done from PHP:

```
<a href="page.php" target="_parent">
```

I'm using Symfony2 so will need to get it working in that too.

No JavaScript. PHP only (if possible).

Comment: Try `target="_top"` instead, it should work in PHP. Just either escape by using `target=\"_top\"` or `target='_top'`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you've read this

Comment: `_top` will break out of any frame.

Comment: How do you use it in PHP?

Comment: Maybe this will do `<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://<?php echo $url; ?> target='_top'";</script>`?

Comment: You could also try `echo("<script language=\"javascript\">"); echo("top.location.href = \"http:/www.example.com/somepage.php\";"); echo("</script>");`

Comment: Try both of my suggestions above and let me know if they worked for you.

Comment: As others have stated below, you can't do it in PHP. You must resort to a Javascript method, or make it an echoed clickable link that people will see. Those are your only options. Sorry, but I didn't write `PHP`. Had I written it, would've definitely added that option ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in PHP - if the browser is trying to load the page in a frame, then sending a `Location` header will simply load the new page in the frame too.

If you're trying to stop others from putting your site in a frame, you'd have to use JavaScript to detect it and do the redirect, otherwise `target="_top"` is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller in Symfony 2, return some variable (for example reloadMyIframe) then, when you want to reload your iframe. Then in view (twig probably), put something like this

```
{% if reloadMyIframe == true %}

// Add somethin like this <script...>window.parent.location.href = "http://jourTaret.dmn"

{% endif %}
```

If your view in Symfony is in PHP, you can use same logic just type it with php if statement.

As the guys have already said, there is no way to accomplish what you are trying to just with PHP or from Symfony controller.